# Find sum'd subset of data from larger data's group-by (subset being pre-grouping, reliant on grouping to determine)

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

So I've got a problem that I am trying to solve purely in mySQL (I know it's a lot easier if I add in PHP, but I'm trying to avoid that for reasons outside the scope of this question). I have a query that combines a lot of tables/table data and returns the following relevant data (extra fields removed for my question):

| Person | Day | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 6 |
| B | 1 | 5 |
| A | 2 | 7 |
| C | 2 | 6 |
| A | 3 | 5 |
| B | 3 | 5 |
| C | 3 | 5 |
| D | 3 | 5 |
| A | 4 | 7 |
| B | 4 | 5 |
| A | 5 | 7 |
| D | 5 | 5 |
| A | 6 | 6 |
| B | 6 | 5 |
| C | 6 | 6 |
| D | 6 | 5 |
| A | 7 | 5 |
| B | 7 | 5 |
| C | 7 | 5 |
| D | 7 | 6 |

I want to find the sum of each individual's sales, starting at N with N being the first occurrence of them in the table, and going through N+3 (actually it would be a week within a month+ of data, but to limit my sample data I'm asking for N+3 within a week here). The complication is that N is different for each person, with A & B being N=1 (so days 1, 2, 3, 4); C having N = 2 (& 3,4,5); and D having N = 3 (& 4, 5, 6). 'A' worked every day, so has 4 entries (N, N+1, N+2, N+3) but the others have missed days and won't have the same number of entries to be added up. I would be performing `group by` + `sum(sales)` commands on these results to get the total sales within the sub-timeframe of each person.

So quick recap/re-explanation: I have a large timeframe where workers are working, and I want to find the total amount of sales that they made within a changing subset of time limited by the larger timeframe, with the subset starting based upon the first occurrence of each person, calculated individually, and differing numbers of entries within that subset. I am trying to do this purely in SQL if possible, wrapping the new query around my already-written sub-query that gives the previously mentioned table results, to get the results by running a single (large, complex, etc) query.

Comment: (Although the 'complication' doesn't seem like much of a complication)

Comment: Presumably, you're not really storing 'day'?

Comment: In my live data, Person would be a name, day would be a full date stamp. My confusion is how to group-by while only taking the first 4 results of each person under the grouping (as even D who starts on day 3, would not be be including day 7). I recall seeing a similar question a couple years ago where the Q wanted just the first result and they were given a limit 1 for a sub-query I believe, but I cannot find that question and don't know if the difference between limit 1 and limit 4 is significant.

Comment: I suggest you revise your question to more accurately reflect the actual scenario, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: ok, so I was able to bring in PHP after all to solve this problem (required bringing in someone else within the company which I had hoped to avoid initially), and pretty much ran through all the results without grouping on the SQL level. I still would like to know if it is possible to find a subset without pre-determined (or even constant between entries) starting / end points of where clause delimeters - if it's not possible without moving beyond SQL as I have done already, then I would appreciate knowing that so I can stop thinking about this issue.

Comment: I suspect it's very straightforward.